# "leak" converting .csv to .nc using xarray in some points

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, netcdf, python-xarray

I'm trying to transform some points that are tabulated .csv in a netcdf file.

This is my .csv file: [https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhZf0QH5jEVSjWfnPtJjJgmXf-i0?e=WEpMyU](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

In my spreadsheet, I have the unique location of each point, not regular for all area but points are spaced by 0.1 degree, an SP value per year up to 100 years forward.

To work with this data, I needed something like other sources that use netcdf data tabled in sp(time, lat, lon). So, I can evaluate and visualize the values ​​of this specific region by year (using panoply or ncview for example).

For that, I came up with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

csv_file = 'example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["lon", "lat"], var_name="time", value_name="sp")
df['time']= pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.set_index(["time", "lat", "lon"])
df = df.astype('float32')
xr = df.to_xarray()
xc = xr.fillna(0)
xc.to_netcdf(csv_file + '.nc')
```

And I got a netcdf file like this: `https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhZf0QH5jEVSjWfnPtJjJgmXf-i0?e=WEpMyU`

At first, my code seems to work and create my netcdf file without problems, however, I noticed that in some places I am creating some "leakage" of points, or interpolating the same values ​​in some direction (north-south and west-east) when it shouldn't happen.

If you do a simple plot before converting to xarray you can see there are 3 west segments and one south segment

```
xr.sp[0].plot()
```

[image]

And this ends up being masked a bit when I fill the NaN with 0 and plot it again:

```
xc.sp[0].plot()
```

[image]

Checking the netcdf file using panoply I got something similar as well:

[image]

So I've start to check every-step of my code to see if I miss something.. my first guess was the melt part but I not 100% sure because if I plot df I can't see any leaking or extrapolation in the same region:

```
joint_axes = seaborn.jointplot(
    x="lon", y="lat", data=df, s=0.5
)
contextily.add_basemap(
    joint_axes.ax_joint,
    crs="EPSG:4326",
    source=contextily.providers.CartoDB.PositronNoLabels,
);
```

[image]

So anyone have any idea what's happening here?

EDIT:

Now a solution that would help me at the moment would be to fill in the missing coordinates with a value equal to 0 within my domain area using the minimum and maximum latitudes and longitudes.

My first (and unconventional) idea was to create a 0.1 x 0.1 grid with values equal to zero and feed this grid with my existing values.

However, the method using reindex would help me and I would be able to execute it in a few lines. My doubt is whether I should do this before or after the `df.melt` in my code.

I'm in this situation:

```
csv_file = '/Users/helioguerraneto/Desktop/example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)  
lonmin, lonmax = df['lon'].min(), df['lon'].max() 
latmin, latmax = df['lat'].min(), df['lat'].max()  
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["lon", "lat"], var_name="time", value_name="sp") 
df['time']= pd.to_datetime(df['time']) 
df = df.set_index(["time", "lat", "lon"]) 
df = df.astype('float32') 
xr = df.to_xarray() 
xc = xr.reindex(lat=np.arange(latmin, latmax, 0.1), lon=np.arange(lonmin, lonmax, 0.1), fill_value=0)
xc.to_netcdf(csv_file + '.nc')
```

Seems like reindex is the way but I need to keep original data. I was expecting some zeros but not in all area:

[image]

EDIT2:

I think I found something might help! My goal now could be same what's happing here: [How to interpolate latitude/longitude and heading in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682416/how-to-interpolate-latitude-longitude-and-heading-in-pandas)

But instead of interpolation by the nearest I just could match with the exactly coordinates. Maybe the real problem here is mix 100 hundred grids in the end..

Any suggestions?

Comment: this can actually happen when plotting a pcolormesh plot when you have blocks of missing lat/lons from your grid, so the coordinates passed to matplotlib jump from one lat or lon to another. You can usually fix this by reindexing the data to include every lat/lon combo within the domain, e.g. `da.reindex(lat=np.arange(latmin, latmax, 0.1), lon=np.arange(lonmin, lonmax, 0.1))` or whatever your grid spec is

Comment: Have you plotted this with ncview? This will not run into the issues mentioned above. Have you read the csv into pandas and plotted it with scatter to make sure those coords aren’t in the data?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado this make sense to me because I am not covering 100% of all area boundary with info so matplot is doing that. I really enjoy your approaching and I was trying to figure out something like that but you mentioned one line code (more elegant). Do you mind to help me out with that? I did follow if I should use this after or before melt part.

Comment: ```csv_file = 'example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

lonmin, lonmax = df['lon'].min(), df['lon'].max()
latmin, latmax = df['lat'].min(), df['lat'].max()

df = df.reindex(lat=np.arange(latmin, latmax, 0.1), lon=np.arange(lonmin, lonmax, 0.1))
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["lon", "lat"], var_name="time", value_name="sp")
df['time']= pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.set_index(["time", "lat", "lon"])
df = df.astype('float32')
xr = df.to_xarray()
xc = xr.fillna(0)
xc.to_netcdf(csv_file + '.nc')
```

Comment: @RobertWilson seems you are right. I tested again using ncview and I got a different behavior than using panoply. I did something similar to scatter plot in my last figure. Thanks!

Comment: @HLGNT great glad we're on the right track. can you modify your question to include your example rather than posting it in comments? edit logs are always visible so there's no need to post "edit" or anything - just update your question to provide more info.

Comment: oh! I meant `da` as in DataArray - I think you should do the reindex in xarray. So in your case, this would be right before the write, using the varible name `xc`. you could also provide `fill_value=0` to `reindex` if you want the values to be zero, not NaN. But pcolormesh should still plot this fine if you have NANs - the issue is due to the missing coordinates

Comment: note that reindex is not interpolating to a new grid or anything, so you have to be sure that the values you reindex to exactly match the coordinate labels of your existing array if you want to preserve all your data. you could check this with something like `new_lats = np.arange(xc['lat'].min(), xc['lat'].max(), 0.1); assert xc["lat"].isin(new_lats).all()`. If not, you may need to adjust the grid spec (could be on the cell center rather than edge?) or round the values if you're falling prey to floating point errors.

Comment: Seems I am missing something. Actually, I was capable to use set all region to 0 but I did not preserve my original data. All values have already been rounded previously. The problem now is that I need to fill in the blanks with zero following that same grid.